# No netwotk option in vmware fusion

Tags: macos, windows-xp, vmware, vmware-fusion

I have a macbook with a 10.5.8 version.
I'm trying to use vmware fusion with windows xp.

I have a perfectly good internet connection in my mac enviourment but when i go into xp i have no connection. 
Iv'e seen all kind of solution to the problem but havent seen one when were you go into  xp
menu bar -> virtual machine -> settings : and when i press network there is nothing there.
and the + is in grey and you can't press it.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the "Virtual Machine" menu and select `(Re)install VMWare Tools`. This will install the relevant network and display drivers for your guest OS. It may trigger or require a reboot of your guest VM, but try that option first.

Following that, you will have several networking options. Choose `NAT` if you want to leverage the MacBook's network connection/IP. Select `Bridged` if you want the Windows VM to occupy its own IP address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing guest-additions for the guest (windoiws) xp system. Your mac environment may not supply apropriate driver for ethernet controller in xp.

Comment: i used to have the connection but it suddenely stopped